# XGBClassifier is slow and does not print any output despite passing verbose parameter

Tags: python, dataframe, xgboost

I have the following code:

```
from xgboost import XGBClassifier

print(df_train.shape)
print(df_train_labels.shape)

clf = clf.fit(df_train, df_train_labels, verbose=True)
print("after fit")
```

Here `df_train` and `df_train_labels` are pandas which I read from a CSV.

The above code prints:

```
(1460, 7)
(1460,)
```

However, nothing else is printed for 10 minutes which means the code is stuck at `clf.fit` so I'm assuming the algorithm shouldn't spend a long time on this.

As you can see, there are only `1460` examples, so I'm assuming the algorithm shouldn't spend a long time on this.

Furthermore, since I passed `verbose=True`, I would have expected the model to print some output, but that is not happening.

Any idea why there is no output printed and why `XGBClassifier` takes such a long time?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation:
https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#module-xgboost.sklearn

It looks like the parameter for printing the progress is called verbosity.
Set it to anything from 0-3 (3 for debug).

```
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
model = XGBClassifier()
setattr(model, 'verbosity', 2)
```

Comment: You don't need to use `setattr`. You can do set the verbosity when you instantiate the `model`:

`model = XGBClassifier(verbosity = 2)`

Comment: ^This doesn't work for me @LuisChavesRodriguez

Answer (score -3):

You should first initialize the model you want to use, in your case `XGBClassifier()`.
A common pipeline to do so is:

```
from xgboost import XGBClassifier

model = XGBClassifier()
model.fit(df_train, df_train_labels)
y_pred = model.predict(df_test)
```